# Testing vitest in nuxt3, spy.on doesn't work in different test case

Tags: nuxt3, vitest

My test code is like below.

```
import * as $customFetch from '@/composables/api/customFetch'

const mockedCustomFetchFail = async (url: string) => { 
return { 
  data: ref(null), 
  error: ref(null), 
  statusCd: 500, 
  pending: ref(false),
  refresh: vi.fn(), 
  execute: vi.fn(), }; 
}; 

const mockedCustomFetch = async (url: string) => { 
return { 
 data: ref({date: '2030-11-16'}), 
 error: ref(null), 
 statusCd: 200, 
 pending: ref(false), 
 refresh: vi.fn(), 
 execute: vi.fn(), 
 }; 
};

describe('tests', async () => {

// vi.spyOn($customFetch, 'customFetch').mockImplementation(mockedCustomFetch);

test('test1', async () => { 
 vi.spyOn($customFetch, 'customFetch').mockImplementation(mockedCustomFetch); 
 const dateStore = useDateStore(); 
 expect(dateStore.date).to.equal('2030-11-16'); 
});

test('test2', async () => { 
 vi.spyOn($customFetch, 'customFetch').mockImplementation(mockedCustomFetchFail);
 const dateStore = useDateStore();
 expect(dateStore.date).to.equal('');
 }); 
})
```

In this test code, both test of vi.spyOn doesn't work and fail these tests. However, If you delete the spyOn for each test and uncomment the first spyOn, only test1 correctly passes the test. Then you change mockedCustomFetch of mockImplementation to mockedCustomFetchFail, test1 is fail and test2 is pass.

How can I spyOn each test and pass ?
If anyone knows how to do this, I would appreciate it.